# Controlador de evento al cambiar el atributo de una etiqueta

Tags: javascript

¿Existe un controlador de evento en JavaScript para cuando se actualice el valor de un atributo? Y más concreto para el caso del `src` de un `img`.

No me refiero al `load` (que se lanza cuando la imagen se ha cargado), sino a antes, a cuando el valor del `src` se cambia (puede pasar un tiempo mientras se descarga la imagen antes de que se lance el `load`).

Por ejemplo, si tengo una imagen y a través del código se cambia el `src`, desde ese momento hasta que se descargue y muestre la imagen, me gustaría mostrar un mensaje de "Cargando".

¿Es algo que existe en JavaScript directamente (y cómo)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se puede utilizar un [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (revisar la [compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility)).

Consiste en crear un objeto:

```
var miMO = new MutationObserver(callback);
```

Y llamar a `observe(nodo, opciones)` con el nodo que se observará y las opciones para determinar cuándo se dispara el callback. Las opciones son un objeto [MutationObserverInit](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) que acepta:

- **`childList`** - Si es true, observa adiciones y eliminaciones de nodos hijos (incluyendo textNodes).
- **`attributes`** - Si es true, observa las mutaciones en los atributos del nodo.
- **`characterData`** - Si es true, observa las mutaciones en la data del nodo.
- **`subtree`** - Si es true, también observa las mutaciones en los descendientes del nodo.
- **`attributeOldValue`** - Si es true (con `attributes` en true), se dispara antes del cambio en un atributo.
- **`characterDataOldValue`** - Si es true (con `characterData` en true), se dispara antes del cambio en data.
- **`attributeFilter`** - Un array de atributos si sólo se quiere observar una lista específica.

El beneficio de utilizar un [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) es que se dispara con cualquier modificación en el DOM. Se puede disparar cuando se modifica desde código, con un script del usuario, o incluso cuando el mismo usuario edita el DOM manualmente. Por tal motivo, es importante que los filtros pasados como opciones sean lo más específicos posibles, para que el uso de recursos no sea tan intensivo.

Por ejemplo, para observar las mutaciones en el src de una imagen:

```
var miImg = document.getElementById('idDeImg'),
    miMO  = new MutationObserver(callback);

miMO.observe(miImg, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: [
        'src'
    ]
});
```

Y luego se llamará al callback con una colección [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationRecord). En particular, de cada elemento de la colección, nos interesará verificar que `.attributeName == "src"`. Es decir, que se haya cambiado esa propiedad específica. Esta comprobación es redundante con los filtros que pasamos recién, pero lo dejo en caso de que se quiera agregar otra mutación que dispare el callback.

**Ejemplo**:

```js
var miImg = document.getElementById('idDeImg'),
    miMO  = new MutationObserver(callbackMO);

miMO.observe(miImg, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    attributeFilter: ['src']
});

function callbackMO(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.attributeName == "src") { // <- redundante
            console.log('Se cambió la imagen de', mutation.oldValue, 'a', mutation.target.src);
        }
    });
}


//Prueba cambiando el src
function cambiarSrc() {
    miImg.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4AWis.jpg";
}
```

```html
<img id="idDeImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/knEtbs.jpg">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="cambiarSrc()" value="Probar cambiar el src">
```

Comment: Leí en [esta pagina](http://casamadrugada.net/tutoriales/javascript/saber-cuando-algo-cambia-en-el-dom-con-mutationobserver/) que `MutationObserver` *solo acepta un único elemento y no una colección de ellos* **¿Es verdad eso o solo aplica para el ejemplo se esa pagina?**

Comment: @JuankGlezz Hasta donde llega mi imaginación, sólo aplica a ese ejemplo (por no querer decir que está equivocado). Así como también entiendo que con los filtros que usé en esta respuesta, sólo se podría disparar un único cambio (el `src` sólo puede cambiar una vez por mutación). Pero es **falso** para el caso general. Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/marianom/zfwytxpg/ ... Esto es especialmente válido con `contentEditable` o cuando el usuario edita el DOM manualmente.

Answer (score 3):

Hasta donde se no hay un evento nativo, pero puedes usar un [proxy ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Proxy) (o usar un [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill) si necesitas ES5) y lanzar un evento personalizado cuando se modifica la propiedad.

El siguiente ejemplo crea un proxy para set y get, y lanza un evento personalizado si la propiedad `src` es modificada.

```js
// preparacion del proxy
function ImageProxy(element) {
  return new Proxy(element, {
    get(target, propKey, receiver) {
      return element[propKey];
    },
    set(target, propKey, value, receiver) {
      // aqui disparas el evento.
      if (propKey === 'src' && target.onsrcchanged) {
        target.onsrcchanged(target[propKey], value)
      }
      target[propKey] = value;
    }
  });
}

let el = document.createElement('img');
document.body.append(el);

// creas el proxy
let elProxy = ImageProxy(el);

// este es el manejador del evento
elProxy.onsrcchanged = function(oldVal, newVal) {
  console.log('se ha modificadoimg.src =', newVal);
}

// aqui cambias 
elProxy.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports';
console.log(elProxy.src);

setTimeout(function() {
  // vuelves a cambiar
  elProxy.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature';
  console.log(elProxy.src);
}, 5000);
```

También es posible hacerlo con `Object.definePropery`, es realmente bastante similar y es compatible con ES5 sin necesidad de polyfils.

```js
function ImageNonProxy(image) {
  Object.defineProperty(image, 'src', {
    set: function(srcAttr) {
      if (image.onsrcchanged) {
        image.onsrcchanged(image.getAttribute('src'), srcAttr)
      }
      image.setAttribute('src', srcAttr);
    },
    get: function() {
      return image.getAttribute('src');
    }
  });
  return image
}

var el = document.createElement('img');
document.body.append(el);

// creas el proxy
let elProxy = ImageNonProxy(el);

// este es el manejador del evento
elProxy.onsrcchanged = function(oldVal, newVal) {
  console.log('se ha modificadoimg.src =', newVal);
}

// aqui cambias 
elProxy.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports';
console.log(elProxy.src);

setTimeout(function() {
  // vuelves a cambiar
  elProxy.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature';
  console.log(elProxy.src);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Existe la [`API MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (`IE11+`)

Utilizando dicha `API` en combinación con el evento `onload` puedes lograr saber exactamente el momento en que se inicio la cargar y cuando terminó (con éxito)

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image');
var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
var btn = document.getElementById('button');

// Creamos un observador y pasamos la función que sera invocada 
// cada vez que se realice alguna mutación
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    // Si la mutacion fue sobre un atributo y especificamente sobre el "src"
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'src') {
      console.log('Load Started!');
      loader.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });    
});
var config = {attributes: true};

// Suscribimos el observer a la img con la config deseada
observer.observe(img, config);

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/xkKw5r8.jpg';
});
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Load Finished!');
  loader.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#image {
  width: 300px;
}

#loader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Cargar imagen</button>
<br/><br/>
<img id="image" />
<div id="loader">Cargando...</div>
```