# Detectar cambios en codigo HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Hola quisiera saber la forma de detectar cambios en una estructura html.
Por ejemplo

```
<html>
 <div><div>
<html>
```

A lo largo del tiempo esa estructura se ira cambiando.quisiera saber si hay alguna forma detectar los cambios..sin tener que usar timeOut en javascript,ya que se hacen peticiones que a apis en un momento puede durar 1000 y en otra 2000.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Quieres detectar si hay mas divs a los largo del tiempo? es decir si inicialmente tienes 2 y luego se crea otro detectar ese nuevo?

Comment: Hice una [pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43292/250) hace algún tiempo. Las respuestas de allí te pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar el API [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), se define un callback que procesa los cambios y luego se le dice que elemento observar junto a la lista de cosas para observar.

En este ejemplo le pongo a observar la lista de nodes hijos, sus atributos y cambios en el árbol de los hijos.

La mayor parte del código mostrado es para simular un ajax con promesas y tiempos variables, además de implementar un console log que no tape el resultado.

Además del agregar items y borrar items, hay 2 botones extra que controlan el observador para empezar a observar y dejar de observar.

En cada item hay 2 botones mas que cambian un atributo o borran el item.

El observer le pasa al callback (cada vez que detecta un cambio) una lista de "mutaciones", en esta lista cada mutación tiene un tipo, y un target o una lista de nodos target, la onda es recorrer las mutaciones y verificar el tipo.

```js
// creamos el observador

const panoptico = new MutationObserver(
  (mutaciones, observer) => {
    for (var m of mutaciones) {
      if (m.type == 'childList') {
        consolog('[espia] Cambió el número de items');
      } else if (m.type == 'attributes') {
        consolog(
          '[espia] El atributo ',
          m.attributeName,
          ' de ',
          m.target.querySelector('h2').innerHTML,
          'fue modificado.');
      }
    }
  }
);

var $dinamico = document.getElementById("dinamico");

// comenzar a observar
document.getElementById("espia").onclick = function() {
  consolog('te estoy viendo');
  panoptico.observe(
    $dinamico, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    },
  );
}

// dejar de observar
document.getElementById("desespia").onclick = function() {
  consolog('ya no se que haces');
  panoptico.disconnect();
}

// resto del code ejemplo



// para que el log no tape las cosas
var consolog = function(...cosas) {
  var logs = document.getElementById('logs');
  cosas.forEach((t) => {
    logs.innerHTML += t + " ";
  });
  logs.innerHTML += "\n";
  logs.scrollTop = logs.scrollHeight;
};

let descripciones = ["arbol", "pera", "batata", "semaforo"];
var start = Date.now();

// timeout random por usar el wifi del hotel
var fetchDescripcion = function(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    consolog('fetching', id);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        id: id % descripciones.length,
        descripcion: descripciones[id % descripciones.length],
      });
    }, (Math.random() * 4 + 2) * 1000);
  });
}

var setDescripcion = function(d) {
  consolog('resolve', d.id, d.descripcion);
  var info = document.createElement('div');
  info.className = "info";
  var nombre = document.createElement('h2');
  nombre.innerHTML = "(" + d.id + ") " + d.descripcion;
  var masinfo = document.createElement('p');
  masinfo.innerHTML = "Marca de tiempo: " + (Date.now() - start);

  var marcaMe = document.createElement('button');
  marcaMe.classList.add("btn", "btn-marcar");
  marcaMe.innerHTML = "&#9055;";
  marcaMe.onclick = function(ev) {
    var elem = ev.target.parentNode;
    elem.classList.toggle('marcado');
  }

  var borraMe = document.createElement('button');
  borraMe.classList.add("btn", "btn-borrar");
  borraMe.innerHTML = "&#8416;";
  borraMe.onclick = function(ev) {
    var elem = ev.target.parentNode;
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
  info.appendChild(nombre);
  info.appendChild(marcaMe);
  info.appendChild(borraMe);
  info.appendChild(masinfo);

  $dinamico.appendChild(info);
}

var getDescripcion = function(id) {
  fetchDescripcion(id).then(x => setDescripcion(x));
}


document.getElementById("pone").onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var dId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    getDescripcion(dId);
  }
}

document.getElementById("saca").onclick = function() {
  while ($dinamico.lastChild) {
    $dinamico.removeChild($dinamico.lastChild);
  }
  start = Date.now();
}
```

```css
#info {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 0
}

#logs {
  height: 160px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-width: 50vw;
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-marcar {
  background: #fe0;
  color: #000;
}

.btn-borrar {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}

.marcado {
  background: #fed;
}

.info {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

h2,
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <nav>
    <button id="pone">agregar 5</button>
    <button id="saca">limpiar</button>

    <button id="espia">empezar a observar</button>
    <button id="desespia">dejar de observar</button>
  </nav>
  <section id="info">
    <PRE id="logs"></PRE>
  </section>
  <section id="dinamico">
    <div>

    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```