# ¿Como escuchar cuando la etiqueta html cambie?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, dom

Mi problema es el siguiente.

Utilizo vue y necesito saber el idioma en el que se encuentra la app.

```
<html lang="es">
```

Cuando el idioma cambia en la app necesito notar ese cambio en una instancia no relacionada.

intente esto no me funciona.

```
$('html').change(function(){
    alert()
})
```

Estoy utilizando dos instancias dado a que estoy utilizando un empaquetador de librerías.

tengo una instancia que contiene barras de menus etc.
y una que contiene la seccion actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando cambian el idioma esta dentro de la instancia del template pero no de la sección.

Lo que quiero hacer es actualizar la etiqueta

```
<html lang='Esto es lo que quiero actualizar'>
```

Y que cuando ocurra esto que mi segunda instancia de vue escuche este cambio para que cambie el idioma

Comment: vas a usar jQuery cuando tienes vue??

Comment: No se como escuchar una variable cuando esta fuera de la instancia

Comment: para que quieres saber el idioma, podrias dar mas contexto de eso y hasta la respuesta podria ser mas facil,  cuando trabajas con frameworks como angular react vue recomienda modificar el dom con la misma herramienta que estas desarrollando caso extremo usan jQuery

Comment: evento change solo aplica a elementos `input` `textarea` y `select`

Comment: Esta pregunta se podría considerar un duplicado de [otra pregunta que hice anteriormente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43292/250) en el sitio. Puedes usar `MutationObserver` para detectar el cambio en el atributo `lang` de la etiqueta `html` tal y como lo explican en las respuestas.

Comment: No aplica, para esa pregunta existe el evento "DOMSubtreeModified" por lo cual se puede escuchar cuando cambie el la propiedad src o alguna otra de un elemento. sin embargo no aplica para la etiqueta html

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega ¿cómo no aplica? Acabo de crear un ejemplo y lo detecta sin problemas.

Answer (score 4):

En JavaScript puro, sin necesidad de usar jQuery o vue, puedes crear un [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) para detectar el cambio en el atributo `lang` de la etiqueta `<html>`. Entonces cuando se llame a la función de *callback* tras la mutación, puedes hacer operaciones con vue.

El código sería muy simple (comentado):

```
// crea una mutación que llamará a la función callback cuando ocurra
const muta = new MutationObserver(callback);

// observa los cambios
muta.observe(
             document.querySelector('html'),  // en la etiqueta HTML
             {
                attributes: true,             // en atributos
                attributeFilter: ['lang']     // sólo para el atributo lang
             }
            );

// función a llamar cuando ocurra un cambio
function callback() {
  // aquí pondrías tu código
}
```

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
function cambiaIdioma() {
  const html = document.querySelector("html")
  const idioma = html.getAttribute("lang");
  html.setAttribute("lang", idioma === "en" ? "es" : "en");
}

// esta es la parte que te interesa
const html = document.querySelector("html")
const muta = new MutationObserver(callback);
muta.observe(html, {attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['lang']});
function callback() {
  // aquí pondrías tu código, yo voy a actualizar el número de clicks
  const veces = document.querySelector("#veces");
  veces.innerHTML = (parseInt(veces.innerHTML) + 1);
}
```

```css
html[lang="en"] #texto::before {
  content: "The language is English.";
}

html[lang="es"] #texto::before {
  content: "El idioma es español.";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test MutationObserver en html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="cambiaIdioma()">Cambia Idioma</button>
    <div id="texto"></div>
    <div>El idioma cambió <span id="veces">0</span> veces.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```